# Xcode 5: Container embedded UITableViewController does not display correctly

Tags: xcode, uicontainerview

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a container view in the following way:

[image]

Without doing any work on this set up I get the following display:

[image]

notice the first row shows a larger space than the normal spacing of these rows. Is there something that needs correcting to get this to display properly?

I have a couple of other scenes that do the same thing which doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1):

The UITableView is taking its frame from the bounds of the container view, but the container view looks like it is not the full size that you want. Try aligning the container view's borders up to the top and bottom of its view controller's view. I assume everything is embedded inside a UINavigationController but the usual case with iOS7 is you want the child views to take up the whole screen and sit under the navigation bar (with a translucent bar). The tableview will adjust accordingly so the first row isn't hidden.

Here is a picture of what I mean:
[image]